# Additional space on clearfix parent

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I have a layout wherein the sidebar is fixed and the main contents container is fluid.

```
        <div id="contents" class="wrapper group">
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <!-- sidebar stuff here -->
            </aside>
            <section id="main-contents">
                <!-- content here -->
            </section>
        </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QzsL5/2/

When I apply the class "group" to the **ul** of feeds, the **ul** has extra pixels added to its height, it doesn't just wrap the **li** inside it. But when I delete the sidebar, this extra height isn't shown. I noticed that the bottom of the **ul** is aligned with the bottom of the sidebar.

I don't know why it behaves this way. Help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might be missing is a 'clearfix' solution within your css.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzsL5/4/

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

After implementing the above within your css, add the following class name 'clearfix' to your UL.

Comment: Hey, @Starboy, that worked! Thanks. but would you happen to know why? because the "clearfix" I used is the latest version according to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ I just replaced the .clearfix with .group by the way

Comment: @omgdork Did you have it incorporated into your fiddle you previous posted?

Comment: Also, I noticed that there's still some space between the <ul> and the <p id="see-more">. Why is that? (not talking about the margin, you can remove the margin and still see some 2-3pixels of space between them)

Comment: nope. I just used .group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
} the update from August 2012.

Comment: Not a problem, for the clearfix the one you posted from css tricks WILL WORK. The reason I think you ran into some troubles is you might have added other attributes. Best case in the future just add the class 'clearfix' onto items.

Comment: Whoops sorry. There. Wait, which attributes might that be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31756/discussion-between-omgdork-and-starboy)